# Notifications widgets not updating

Tags: macos, crash, notifications, dashboard-widget

I have a problem with Notifications widget. I can't receive an update for the widget. (I enable only 1 `Stock` widget now).

There is crash: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz4iftfbbcmd9gi/crash.txt?dl=0

Crash happened when I opened Notification area.

There are traces:

```
Sep  2 18:18:25 U-MAC com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spigot.ApplicationManager[10354]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Sep  2 18:18:25 U-MAC com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spigot.ApplicationManager): Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
Sep  2 18:18:25 U-MAC ReportCrash[10281]: Saved crash report for ApplicationManager[10354] version 1.1 (1.1.18) to /Users/bushev/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ApplicationManager_2015-09-02-181825_U-MAC.crash
Sep  2 18:18:25 U-MAC ReportCrash[10281]: Removing excessive log: file:///Users/bushev/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ApplicationManager_2015-09-02-181457_U-MAC.crash
Sep  2 18:18:27 U-MAC LookupViewService[38935]: Error in CoreDragRemoveTrackingHandler: -1856
Sep  2 18:18:27 U-MAC LookupViewService[38935]: Error in CoreDragRemoveReceiveHandler: -1856
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the my solution: http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-spigot/

After removing spigot all works fine!